# Recebendo null parametros HttpPatch Odata V4

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Salve foks,

Estou com dificuldade em passar valores para o controller utilizando o verbo HttpPath

controller:

```
    [EnableQuery]
    [HttpPatch]        
    public async Task<Document> Patch(
        [FromODataUri] int key1,
        [FromODataUri] int key2,
        [FromBody] Delta<Document> deltaSales)
    {
      /// logic ...
    }
```

Request: http://localhost:1146/odata/Document(key1=516820392,key2=1)

ao receber na controller estou obtendo valores zerados.

Comment: Com o httpPost funciona ?

Comment: O deltaSales também está a passar zerado ?

Comment: sim, com httppost funciona, e o delta tambem está vindo zerado

Comment: Certifique que  está mandado os dados pelo HttpPatch.